# Laravel 8 Images of Subpages/Routes are not Loading

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, apache2, laravel-8

all the images of my Laravel 8 Subpages/Routes are not Loading. It seems like a misconfiguration of my .htaccess file in the public directory. I cant find whats causing the problem. All the Images on the Startpage/index Site load completily fine. The Site is running on a Apache2 Webserver in a Subdirectory "/blog".

Here is my .htaccess File from the public directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /blog/

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what URL/URI are you using for these images in your HTML? and by subpage you mean a route?

Comment: Yes i mean a route. To import the Images i just use the Path: "./images/image.png". It is maybe also important to mention that i installed laravel in a subfolder called "/blog" on my apache server. I think that might also cause a problem

Comment: don't use relative paths ... the browser will be trying to find a path from the current basepath, I would say use the `url` helper to generate an absolute path but not sure how that will work for you with your setup .... by import you mean the src attribute of an img tag?

Comment: I used for the path now a asset url which workes fine with any images in the ./public/image directory. But when i want to access images stored in ./storage/app/public/ over a storage symlink to ./public/storage i get a 403 Forbidden Error Code.